# How to build a project generated by CMake for MinGW makefiles?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build SFML's source code after I've ran the directory through CMake and after CMake generated the makefiles. I have no idea how though.

This is how the directory where I've set CMake to dump it's generation to:
[image]

Comment: You have to run `make` from this folder to build it. Open a console, navigate to the directory and write `make`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That’s almost correct. MinGW calls its make mingw32-make.

Comment: On linux I use `cmake --build .` to build my project. It calls the according build command. It works with `make` and `ninja`. I don't know if it also works with MinGW.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I thought make was only on Linux, but I doublechecked and downloaded a fresh one.

Then, I refreshed the page and saw @ThomasSablik's answer and that works too, better than downloading some third tool to do the job.

Comment: Can you put your solution as the answer @ThomasSablik so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux I use

```
cmake --build .
```

to build my project. It calls the according build command. It works with `make` and `ninja`. Probably it works on Windows with MinGW.

Remember that cmake doesn't come with a build system. It only calls the commands. You have to install the build system you want to use.